# How install ubuntu on vmware

Tags: vmware

I want to install ubuntu on vmware, I have downloaded the OS file from ubuntu web site, how to go ahead. Like for RHEL 6 do I have to download an ISO image file so as to install it or is there some other unique technique?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the .iso as a drive, or, if VMWare doesn't have that option, write the ISO to a USB and allow booting from that within VMWare. I'm assuming you are calling the .iso file the "OS" file, you can't (easily that is) use Wubi to install within VMWare (unless you want to dual boot within a VM? That seems kind of pointless.)